# git asks for username and password although I already paired with ssh key

Tags: ssh, git

I work on a friend's project on Gitlab, and have developer rights there.
I already paired my Gitlab account with my personal ssh key from my current computer. Why does it still ask for my email address and my password when I want to push/pull?

Comment: "*paired my Gitlab account with my personal ssh key*" ... how? How does the log/prompt look like? Do you use https or ssh to connect to repository?

Comment: I generated a public ssh key on my computer and added this key to my profile on Gitlab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was that I cloned the repository with the `https` address into my system. Cloning it with the `ssh` address solved the problem, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29956840/4296244).